# Get id of sqlite database row according to content query

Tags: sqlite

I am trying to delete an item from my `sqlite database`

```
public Integer deleteData (String id){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
       return db.delete(TABLE_NAME, "id" + "=?", new String[]{id});
    }
```

So far, the `delete` query works well. But i am having difficulties to find the particular `id` of a particular row.

I was trying to query the data according to a particular field content.

```
 public Integer getId(String desc, Integer id){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.rawQuery("SELECT id  FROM  fap_table WHERE description = '"+desc+"'" , null);
    return id;
}
```

But i keep getting errors. How do i query the database row to retrieve its id. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code to fetch the id:

```
public int getRow(String desc){
    int id = 0;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT id  FROM  fap_table WHERE description = '"+desc+"'" , null);
    if (cursor != null) {
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) 
            id =  cursor.getInt(0);
        cursor.close();
    }
    db.close();
    return id;
}
```

Your code had the error to not assign the result of `db.rawQuery()` to a cursor object. 
`db.rawQuery()` returns the cursor you need and from this you extract the only column (if it exists) which is the id.  
In case the cursor is empty you return `0`.